# How to escape a regular expression when I include it in another regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to use a string as a regular expression inside another regular expression:

```
my $e = "a+b";
if ('foo a+b bar' =~ /foo ${e} bar/) {
    print 'match!';
}
```

Doesn't work, since Perl treats `+` as a special character. How do I escape it without changing the value of `$e`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`\Q` and `\E`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#quotemeta), which treats regexp metacharacters between them as literals:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;

my $e = "a+b";
if ('foo a+b bar' =~ /foo \Q$e\E bar/) {
    say 'match!';
}
```

Comment: Actually, what `\Q` does is defined in [perldoc perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Escape-sequences) as: `\Q          quote (disable) pattern metacharacters until \E`: In other words, It runs quotemeta() on the string between. It is a useful mechanic to know about, a literal Perl function being tied to an escape sequence. Also for instance `\L` runs `lc()`. It does not only apply to regexes, but also double quoted strings, so you could do: `my $e = "\Qa+b\E"`

Comment: There's also the `quotemeta` function which does the same thing as `\Q...\E`. I think it's more readable in most cases.